# How to set up server and deploy user for RoR on CentOS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, centos, centos7

I have already installed ruby throught rbenv, rails through gems and set up `nginx` service that do port forwarding to `localhost:3000` on which `puma` (RoR server) is listening. Both are being run by root and its all working fine. It all was done from root directory. I also wonder if its good way to do just port forwarding, cause when I looked at some tutorials about it they were way more complicated (making puma socket and make nginx to point at socket, using passenger etc).

Also for safety and access reasons, I'd like have seperate user with less priviledges, which is supporting only this one app and dont have access to anything else. I tried to make `deploy` user, I moved whole app to `/home/deploy` and I couldn't run anything from there as `deploy` user.

```
[deploy@RaV-RoR ~]$ ruby
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

I am totally new at this and I couldn't really find any tutorial about this. Do I need to install ruby and everything again in `/home/deploy`? How do I do that if I dont have permissions to install ruby? Should I give root priviledges to `deploy` user and then take them away in order to install all those thing? Or can I access them somehow using root catalogue.

I'd like to do it "good way" and my question is how to do it.

Comment: So... You tried to "cheat" by making everything `root`, and now you're stuck trying to unwind it. Lesson learned: Don't cheat by making everything `root`; you'll come back to regret it :)

Comment: I would advise that you install ruby via rbenv, as the `deploy` user: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation. Don't use the system ruby.

Comment: Well, it was first time I was doing it and actually and I wonder if I should just give `sudo` priviledges to `deploy` user to install all this stuff again, but the thing is it will be same as making another `root` user, right?

Comment: This is why tools like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) exist. It works with Nginx and manages the server process as well, something that Puma doesn't necesarily do. [Worth considering](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Puma-vs-Phusion-Passenger).

Comment: @RaV The `deploy` user will probably need `sudo` privileges, but not **password-less `sudo`**. (Except maybe for specific commands, such as restarting the server.) And if you install ruby with `rbenv`, then you should not be running `sudo` for basic commands like `bundle install`.

Comment: @tadman I was using `systemctl` in order to run Nginx and Puma services. I have set up autostart options etc.

Comment: This is probably better addressed on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) than here as it's not expressly about programming.